# Tizen TV 4.0 and 4.5 Web App Signalr not connect

Tags: reactjs, tizen, tizen-tv, tizen-tv-emulator

I developed a web application with ReactJs and installed the same application as a tizen tv widget.
I am establishing longpolling connection with SignalR on remote server. It works on version 5.5 of the browser and emulator, but not 4.0 and 4.5 on a real device. In versions 4.0 and 4.5, it sends a request for connection, but I do not get an error.
I don't see a problem with Tizen and Samsung permissions.
It is stated in the documents that 4.0 and above support socket connection.
I couldn't tell the difference between the two versions.

Tizen configs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/ReactEmpty" version="0.2.1" viewmodes="maximized">
<tizen:application id="n5YnSlcGyE.ReactPanel" package="n5YnSlcGyE" required_version="2.3"/>
<content src="index.html"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
<feature name="http://www.samsungdforum.com/feature/Mouse"/>
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/prelaunch.support" value="true"/>
<name>ReactPanel</name>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/contentsdownload"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/widgetdata"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/push"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/unlimitedstorage"/>
<tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="enable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/></widget>
```

Build methods:

```
"tizen-build": "rm -rf build && craco build && cp tizen/* build && tizen build-web -- build && tizen package -t wgt -s thisSignatureName -- build/.buildResult",
"tizen-deploy": "tizen install -n ReactPanel.wgt -- build/.buildResult",
"tizen-full-deploy": "yarn tizen-build && tizen install -n ReactPanel.wgt -- build/.buildResult"
```

I need your good ideas. Thnx.

Comment: You had any succes in solving this issue? Have an angular project using websockets and on TV it works while in Developper mode, but when I switch to "normal" TV mode the tizen web application will freeze/hang :(

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a solution and closed the project. I hope you can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build with Tizen studio instead, a debug build would help to identify the problem immediately with the inspector

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to compile an external project with Tizen Studio. Do you have a suggestion for a solution for this?

Comment: Open Tizen studio, and create a new project there, that will give you the proper boilerplate to run on a TV, then open the project folder from Tizen studio, paste your web app inside there and that's it

Comment: I will try, thanks.

Comment: Opening an Angular project in Tizen Studio takes ages and most of the time crashes, as tizen studio proceeds to check and compile every node package dependencies. :(

Comment: I had similar problem. So I couldn't debug.

Comment: @newbiehere, try to tune the settings inside Tizen studio